# How to make PHP Query to Delete SQL Table Rows if Data is Older than One Year

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, time, sql-delete

My table, `tracking_orders`, has a column named `order_time`. When a new row is made, data is created like so to be put into that column:

```
$order_time= date('F j, Y');
```

When I insert a new row, I use the code:

```
  $sql = "insert into tracking_orders (order_time) values ('".$order_time."')";
```

Today, if I used that query the data for that column would read: `April 8, 2014`

I am trying to make a delete query to find any rows in the table that is older than 1 year, and then delete them. So if I made a row last year on this same day, April 8, then it would be deleted. If the `order_time` column data was April 9, 2013, then it would be left alone.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
delete from sh_cart where shsc_date< DATE_ADD(NOW(), Interval -12 MONTH);
```

Check:
[link]
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

If your column is VARCHAR:

```
delete from tracking_orders where STR_TO_DATE(order_time, '%M %e, %Y')< DATE_ADD(NOW(), Interval -12 MONTH);
```

Comment: how about using GETDATE()? and don't for get to mention a way for this to run (a database job or some scheduled daily task)

Comment: It says incorrect syntax near MONTH. Also, my table data for the column displays `April 8, 2014`, exactly.

Comment: Well, it seems that your column is VARCHAR.. then you have to convert it as date using STR_TO_DATE function - STR_TO_DATE(order_time, '%M %d, %Y')

Comment: you do know that reference a mysql link in a sql server question

Comment: I appreciate the help. Check out my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948535/how-to-delete-mssql-table-datetime-getdate-columns-if-they-are-one-year-old-or and maybe you can help me here, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're storing the date as a string (VARCHAR) and not as a proper DATE type. This format doesn't allow you to use SQL's native date functions such as `DATE_DIFF()` or `DATE_ADD()`

In the future, I highly recommend, if possible, changing your column to a DATE type and storing the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. You can reformat it to a user friendly format when displaying, but in a database standard numerical data is always better (especially if this table gets large)