# How to Delete MSSQL Table Datetime GETDATE() Columns if they are One Year Old or Older Using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, time, sql-delete

My column is named `order_date` and the data for it is:

```
datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
```

This will make data appear as:

```
Apr 8 2014 3:24PM
```

I am wondering what PHP Query I can use to delete any rows in this MSSQL table if they are one year old or older.

I would also like a way to test if this works. (IE: Modifying a current row's `order_date` column to make it a year older.)

If anyone can help me with this it is greatly appreciated. T

Comment: PHP is irrelevant for this question. It's purely an SQL question... unless you're generating your "last year" dates in php, in which case it's vaguely php-related, but still mostly sql-only.

Comment: Not quite. You can modify an SQL table through PHP. For example `DELETE FROM real_tracking_orders where STR_TO_DATE(order_time, '%M %e, %Y')< DATE_ADD(NOW(), Interval -12 MONTH)`.

Comment: yes, but that's just sql. it'd be the SAME sql regardless of which language you were using: c, C#, perl, ruby, blah blah blah

Comment: No, because you are using PHP, too. This is not just SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from tracking_orders where DATEDIFF (year, order_date, GETDATE()) > 1
```

Check here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: How can I test if this works? Currently all of my rows were created today, so they are all basically `Apr 8 2014 3:24PM`.

Comment: just change the datepart in the DATEDIFF and put it 'hour'.
`delete from tracking_orders where DATEDIFF (hour, order_date, GETDATE()) > 1`

will delete all records older than an hour

Comment: Thank you, it works. May I offer you an exchange of up votes?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE order_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```

This query can make use of indexes defined on `order_date` column if any.

Comment: Thank you, for the help. May I offer an exchange of up votes?

Comment: exchange of upvotes? are we now buying and selling votes? Please do not upvote my answer as I am not going to upvote your question, The reason I will not upvote your question is because you could have googled it and found the solution there in a lot less time then it took you to post a question here. The solution I have given you is better then the solution you have accpeted as your answer because this will make use of any indexes on your table. Anyway you do not trade votes here, the best answer gets more attention and votes. Thank you.

Comment: I was simply implying that we both have earned an up vote. I think just because information can be obtained through Google does not make Stack Overflow a last resort. Although, I personally have tried to use Google to find this answer and have had no luck. I think you have earned an up vote because your answer is effective. I believe I have earned an up vote because my question is relevant and useful to the stack overflow community.